# Linkedin API Company Post with image and link

Tags: php, image, linkedin-api

I try to use the linkedin API to post an image with a link to our homepage to a linkedin-company-page.

I tried the following PHP-Code for the json object, which I posted to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts`, but with this it seems like you can only use images, which are already uploaded to linkedin, not a simple URL.

```
$json = json_encode(array(
            'author' => 'urn:li:organization:123456789',
            'lifecycleState' => 'PUBLISHED',
            'visibility' => array('com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility' => 'PUBLIC'),
            'specificContent' => [
                'com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent' => [
                    'shareCommentary' => [
                        'text' => "MyText...",
                    ],
                    'shareMediaCategory' => 'ARTICLE',
                    'media' => [
                            [
                            'status' => 'READY',
                            'description' => [
                                'text' => "MyTitle...",
                            ],
                            'media' => '[
                                        {
                                            "status": "READY",
                                            "originalUrl": "https://example.com/image.png"
                                        }
                            ]',
                            'title' => [
                                'text' => "MyTitle...",
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ));
```

The API throws the error
`{"message":"ERROR :: \/specificContent\/com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent\/media\/0\/media :: Urn doesn't start with 'urn:'. Urn: [\n {\n \"status\": \"READY\",\n \"originalUrl\": \"https:\/\/example.com\/temp\/image.png\"\n }\n ] at index 0: [\n {\n \"status\": \"READY\",\n \"originalUrl\": \"https:\/\/example.com\/temp\/image.png\"\n }\n ]\n","status":422}`

I couldn't find any other definitions or parameters to pass a link and an image as a URL. How can I achieve this?